# Axioms of Probability Question

Tags: probability, functions, axioms

I'm stuck on the following axiom of probability question.
Suppose that A,B and C are events. Prove the following:

i) P(A∩B) > P(A) +P(B)−1

Comment: This isn't true.  The formula needs $\ge$ instead of $\gt.$  (Take $A$ and $B$ mutually exclusive and exhaustive; then both sides equal $0.)$

Comment: If  we let $A=B=\Omega$, where $\Omega$ is the sample space, then one has $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\mathbb{P}(\Omega)=1$ and $\mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{P}(B)-1=1$. We cannot have $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)>\mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{P}(B)-1$ since $1\ngtr 1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
1 \geq P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B).
$$
Now add $[-1 + P(A \cup B)]$ on both sides of the inequality. Don't know how to get a strict inequality, though.

Comment: If $P(A\cap B)=0$ and $P(A\cup B)=1$, you can't get a strict inequality.

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  But, it seems others have already emphasized this issue.

Comment: Thanks i finally got that. I think the hint was mean to be for another part of the question so it can be ignored for now.